# A question about circle geometry

Tags: geometry, circles

Three points $A$, $B$ and $C$ are on a circle, $G$. Suppose $\overline{AB}>\overline{AC}$. Let $M$ be the midpoint of the arc of the circle containing the points A and N the point  in $AB$  such that $MN \perp AB$.

I would like to prove that $\overline{AC}=\overline{AN}+\overline{NB}$.

Comment: Sorry, this is utterly incomprehensible. Post it in some language in which you are comfortable, and someone will translate it into English for you.

Comment: Ok Gerry Myerson. I believe that now is correct and intelligible statement of the question.

Comment: So what is the question? What is the $N$ foot?

Comment: Can you explain exactly about point M: it is midpoint for which arc ($\widehat{BC}$ long arc which containing point A )? Is it possible that point C can be between A and B?

Comment: Unlike @Gerry, [I thought I was able to comprehend the first version of the question](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oWgrT.png), but I cannot comprehend it now.

Comment: As $\overline{AB}>\overline{AC}$ then $\overline{AC}=\overline{AN}+\overline{NB}=\overline{AB}$ not true. So, I think  @Rahul Narain is right in his guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [Rahul Narain](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/856/rahul-narain) is right in [his vision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWgrT.png) of you question: it is simple solution to prove that $|BN|=|AN|+|AC|$.

$MG$ - line through the center $O$ of circle. $HG||MN \Rightarrow NIFG$ - rectangle and $|NI|=|FG|$. $|FG|=|AC|$ because of $\angle ABC = \angle FMG$. $|AN|=|IB|$ because $HG||MN$ and both lines are on equal distance from $O$. So we have that $|AC|+|AN|=|NI|+|IB|=|BN|$.

[image]